# Lazy loading of photos on a UIscrollview

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, alassetslibrary

I'm writing a photo gallery like the "official" one on iPhone. It loads 3 UIImageViews from ALAsset (the one on the center, and the previous and the next one on left and right), loading the thumbnail and then the fullScreenImage, replacing its thumbnail.

Everything occurs in the background, with dispatch_async in a serial queue.

My problem is when the user scrolls the photos fast: the app tries to load the thumbnails while it is still loading the fullScreenImage version of the previous photo(s), so the function that should returns the UIimageviews of the thumbnail... doesn't return, and lag occurs.

I can't cancel the tasks that are already running on dispatch_async to give maximum priority to the function that load the thumbnails, so how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is one scenario that the 4 (initially 3) different priority levels for the built-in concurrent queues was intended to address.  Specifically, say you do:

```
dispatch_queue_t high, myImageQueue, myThumbnailQueue;

high = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0L);
myImageQueue = dispatch_queue_create("task.imageQ", NULL);
myThumbnailQueue = dispatch_queue_create("task.thumbQ", NULL);
dispatch_set_target_queue(myThumbnailQueue, high);
```

Now, any work you dispatch_async() to myImageQueue will be of lesser priority than any work you submit to myThumbnailQueue because the target queue for that work has been retargeted at the high priority concurrent queue.  By default, the target queue for a new serial queue is the "normal" priority global concurrent queue, so we don't have to do anything to myImageQueue after creating it.

Comment: hi jkh, thank you very much for your answer. I already tried with different priorities, but with no success. Even if I assign a low priority for the loading of the full photo, when a new request for the thumbnail (hight priority) is enqueued, it seems that the previous one isn't blocked if it's already started. Maybe because of strong disk activity that loading from ALAsset involves...? It seems that priorities can work for intense CPU tasks, but loading from memory isn't helped by prioritization...

Comment: Once a block is already executing, there is no way to preempt it, so you won't see a scenario where high priority queue work interrupts lower priority work in progress - the priority of the queues only determines which pending "work" is executed next.  It seems to me that you need to break the image rendering work up a bit more or have an internal flag you set which causes image rendering to "back off" while thumbnail rendering is in progress, e.g. by sleeping for a few hundred milliseconds or something.  Not efficient, but short of refactoring ALL of your code, that might work!